# disable caching for i18n phrases rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord, internationalization

I'm new to building a rails 3 app with multiple language support. The product requires that the translation team should be able to **updated phrases** from **web interface** and see its effects **on refresh**. They are not concerned about the performance hit this model carries.

So i'm using the gem **i18n-active_record** and its backend with i18n. The problem is, that translations stored in the db are not fetched on every request. I want the system to query the translations table for each key every time it gets the rendering request.

We're to disable this later when the site is mature enough, but this is an essential feature for now. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. We make the custom translation tool in the Active Admin. I noticed that all translations that connected to the frontend are updated but translations that connected to the mails are not updating.
But if I restart a server, translations for emails updates.
Maybe you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: To be precise, I stop the server and then re-launch it, and then the translations for emails are updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could add in your ApplicationController:

```
before_filter { I18n.reload! }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't really comment on using i18n-active_record, but we run a staging server with the `localeapp` gem running in daemon mode. This means that translations can be editing via a GUI by a translator and they appear instantly on the staging server. Might be something worth looking into for you.

Disclosure: I'm a developer for Locale